# ClickHouse- Search within nested fields

Tags: nested, clickhouse

I have a nested field named items.productName wherein I want to check if the product name contains a particular string.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE hasAny(items.productName,['Samsung'])
```

This works only when the product name is Samsung.

I have tried array join

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM test
ARRAY JOIN items
WHERE items.productName LIKE '%Samsung%'
```

This works but it is very slow (~1 sec for 5 million records)

Is there a way to perform like within hasAny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this using arrayFilter function. [ClickHouse docs](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/functions/higher_order_functions/#arraymap-func-arr1)

Query

```
Select * from test where arrayFilter(x -> x LIKE '%Samsung%', items.productName) != []
```

If you do not use != [] then you will get an error "DB::Exception: Illegal type Array(String) of column for filter. Must be UInt8 or Nullable(UInt8) or Const variants of them."

Comment: A better approach to this would be to use the `arrayExists` function: `WHERE arrayExists(x -> x LIKE '%Samsung%', items.productName)`. This eliminates the need to compare to an empty array, and allows ClickHouse to optimise the clause by short circuiting when the first array value that matches is found, rather than needing to iterate the entire array.